# Java to C# Unix Time Conversion

Tags: c#, java, unix-timestamp

I have this Java code that allows the input of a string of that particular format and converts it to Unix time (a `long` type).

```
string input = "2014-03-08T01:00:00-08:00";

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

(long) dateParser.parse(input.getTime())/1000
```

I was wondering is there an equivalent to this in C# that follows the same parameters?

Comment: `cal` appears to be unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. See if it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dateString, format;
            DateTime result;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            dateString = "2010-12-25T05:05:05.888";
            format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff";
            try
            {
                result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(result.Millisecond);
            }
            catch (FormatException fe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fe.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format", dateString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there peter. It appears that this only returns a 3-digit number when I use `2010-12-25T05:05:05.888` as an example. What property would return a format that's like this: http://puu.sh/7mn7D/4a850f37f6.png

Comment: Hey @peter -- I just noticed that the trailing digits of `-07:00` in `2014-03-10T08:00:00-07:00` indicates the time zone. Any ideas what to do with it and include it in the conversion?

Comment: Not sure. You may want to look here and you use it if/as needed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx